# setup.py error when going from python=3.6 to python=3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install this https://github.com/BarisYazici/deep-rl-grasping/tree/master. The instructions create a conda environment with `python=3.6` but installing the library with `python=3.6` returns an error related to opencv. I read here https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#supported-python-versions that opencv does not support `python=3.6`. Here is part of the error message. The full text is too large.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ...
```

and then

```
    File "setup.py", line 309, in main
      cmake_source_dir=cmake_source_dir,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o7beymxl/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 683, in setup
      cmake_install_dir,
    File "setup.py", line 448, in _classify_installed_files_override
      raise Exception("Not found: '%s'" % relpath_re)
  Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2/py.typed'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I then tried creating a conda environment with `python=3.7` `python=3.8` `python=3.9` but the installations all fail and return me the error below. I have zero knowledge on setuptools and setup.py and was wondering if someone can assist.

```
Obtaining file:///home/haziq/deep-rl-grasping
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['config', 'models', 'tests_gripper', 'encoder_files', 'trained_models', 'manipulation_main'].
      
      To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
      setuptools will not proceed with this build.
      
      If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
      on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
      Instead, consider the following options:
      
      1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
      2. use a `src-layout`
      3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names
      
      To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: does it have to be 3.6? otherwise, use the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

you should install `opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.64`，
https://github.com/BarisYazici/deep-rl-grasping/blob/master/setup.py